# gitlab/runner: manifest for moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 not found

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, runner

when i run a pipeline in gitlab-runner.i get an error：

```
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 2.4s done
#1 ERROR: Error response from daemon: manifest for moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 not found
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
ERROR: Error response from daemon: manifest for moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 not found
```

my docker version is 18.03.1-ce
gitlab-runner version is v15.8.1

how to fix it?

gitlab-runner is run as a docker container

Comment: when ii run "docker run moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1"  ,i  got error “Error response from daemon: manifest for moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 not found”,but another host(docker verions is 19.03.12) run "docker pull moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1",is ok.  WHY?should i upgrade docker ?

Comment: it's ok.i edit config.toml,change image = "docker" to image = "docker:stable",and restart runner container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have encountered this problem at the stage of image creation. Errors like this occur due to version incompatibility. Choose other versions for your Docker.

Comment: i edit config.toml,change image = "docker" to image = "docker:stable",and restart runner container. it's ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).